# Updating Debian kernel

Tags: debian, kernel

I'm trying to update my Debian machine to `2.6.32-46` (which is the new [stable](http://packages.qa.debian.org/l/linux-2.6.html)). However, after doing `apt-get update` my `apt-cache search linux-image` shows me:

```
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-486 - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-486
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-686-bigmem
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686 - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-686
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64 - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-openvz-686 - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-openvz-686
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-vser                                                                                                                                                             ver-686-bigmem
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-vserver-686 - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-vserver-686
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-xen-686 - Header files for Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-686
linux-image-2.6.32-5-486 - Linux 2.6.32 for old PCs
linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem-dbg - Debugging infos for Linux 2.6.32-5-686-big                                                                                                                                                             mem
linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem - Linux 2.6.32 for PCs with 4GB+ RAM
linux-image-2.6.32-5-686 - Linux 2.6.32 for modern PCs
linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64 - Linux 2.6.32 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-2.6.32-5-openvz-686-dbg - Debugging infos for Linux 2.6.32-5-openvz-                                                                                                                                                             686
linux-image-2.6.32-5-openvz-686 - Linux 2.6.32 for modern PCs, OpenVZ support
linux-image-2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem-dbg - Debugging infos for Linux 2.6.32-5                                                                                                                                                             -vserver-686-bigmem
linux-image-2.6.32-5-vserver-686-bigmem - Linux 2.6.32 for PCs with 4GB+ RAM, Li                                                                                                                                                             nux-VServer support
linux-image-2.6.32-5-vserver-686 - Linux 2.6.32 for modern PCs, Linux-VServer su                                                                                                                                                             pport
linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-686-dbg - Debugging infos for Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-686
linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-686 - Linux 2.6.32 for modern PCs, Xen dom0 support
linux-image-2.6-486 - Linux 2.6 for old PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-2.6-686-bigmem - Linux 2.6 for PCs with 4GB+ RAM (meta-package)
linux-image-2.6-686 - Linux 2.6 for modern PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-2.6-amd64 - Linux 2.6 for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-2.6-openvz-686 - Linux 2.6 for modern PCs (meta-package), OpenVZ sup                                                                                                                                                             port
linux-image-2.6-vserver-686-bigmem - Linux 2.6 for PCs with 4GB+ RAM (meta-packa                                                                                                                                                             ge), Linux-VServer support
linux-image-2.6-vserver-686 - Linux 2.6 for modern PCs (meta-package), Linux-VSe                                                                                                                                                             rver support
linux-image-2.6-xen-686 - Linux 2.6 for modern PCs (meta-package), Xen dom0 supp                                                                                                                                                             ort
linux-image-486 - Linux for old PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-686-bigmem - Linux for PCs with 4GB+ RAM (meta-package)
linux-image-686 - Linux for modern PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-openvz-686 - Linux for modern PCs (meta-package), OpenVZ support
linux-image-vserver-686-bigmem - Linux for PCs with 4GB+ RAM (meta-package), Lin                                                                                                                                                             ux-VServer support
linux-image-vserver-686 - Linux for modern PCs (meta-package), Linux-VServer sup                                                                                                                                                             port
linux-image-xen-686 - Linux for modern PCs (meta-package), Xen dom0 support
```

So, `2.6.32-46` doesn't seem to be found. How can I update to this kernel?

My sources.list:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib

###### Debian Update Repos
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-proposed-updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-proposed-updates main contrib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: there is no package for linux-image-2.6.32-46 in Debian repo for the moment

That's the current Debian repo state, you can check here http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stable&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=linux-image-2.6.32

Comment: Ah, thanks. So do you have any clue how I **do** update?

Comment: The best way is to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

You're already running it. See `cat /proc/version`.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.32-5-686, so I'm not.

Comment: Mine says Linux 2.6.32-5-686 (Debian 2.6.32-46)...

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel image isn't in the repos yet, you can either;

1. Wait for it to become available
2. Compile the kernel from source (the hard way - not recommended on a debian box)
3. Give up on it.

Why, in particular, do you **need** this kernel?